Coding variables a,b,c to match variable x from another data point
Doing some bioinformatics here in R and I'm very new to it.
In my dataset, I have two data entries per patient. However, patient characteristics were only documented for one of the entries. To do the downstream analysis I want to do, I need to copy the characteristics over to the corresponding entry. I cannot assume the corresponding entry will always be the row below because some patients don't have a second data point or have more replicates.
dput(head(patient.info))

structure(list(Study_ID = c(104, 104, 108, 108, 114, 114), Group = c("BS", 
NA, "BS", NA, "BS", NA), Group2 = c("MO", NA, "MO", NA, "MO", 
NA), Age = c(50.5, NA, 33.5, NA, 51.7, NA), Sex = c("F", NA, 
"F", NA, "F", NA), Sex2 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), Ethnicity = c("A", 
NA, "D", NA, "C", NA), Eth2 = c("EW", NA, "AF M", NA, "EW", NA
)), row.names = c(35L, 36L, 40L, 41L, 49L, 50L), class = "data.frame")

`
Somehow I can use the Study_ID, which corresponds to the patient?
Thanks
I have no clue how to go about this to be honest

Please do not post images of data. Rather use e.g. dput(dataset) or dput(head(dataset)) if the data is too large and add the output to your question through edit.

@AndreWildberg sorry have done so, although to me that format is a lot harder to understand

In the tidyverse, you would use one of the join functions, specifying "Study_ID" as the by argument.  However, to provide concrete advice, we need to see both of your input datasets, not just one of them.  And the output you expect based on those inputs.

patient.info |> dplyr::group_by(Study_ID) |> tidyr::fill(Age:Eth2, .direction = "downup")

One approach is to use fill with a desired fill direction.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

patient.info %>% 
  group_by(Study_ID) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction="downup") %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  Study_ID Group Group2   Age Sex    Sex2 Ethnicity Eth2 
     <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>     <chr>
1      104 BS    MO      50.5 F         2 A         EW   
2      104 BS    MO      50.5 F         2 A         EW   
3      108 BS    MO      33.5 F         2 D         AF M 
4      108 BS    MO      33.5 F         2 D         AF M 
5      114 BS    MO      51.7 F         2 C         EW   
6      114 BS    MO      51.7 F         2 C         EW 


I would extract the characteristics per patient (variable Study_ID) and then join this dataset to your original dataset. When you join, it does not matter where in the dataset the other rows per patient are or wether there are more than two rows per patient.
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(df)

pat <- df[df[, .I[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(Group)))], .(Study_ID)]$V1,]

merge(x = df,y = pat, by="Study_ID", all.x=TRUE)


Try split + zoo::na.locf twice
split(patient.info, patient.info$Study_ID) |>
  lapply(\(x) zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(x), fromLast = TRUE)) |> 
  Reduce(f = rbind)

